# Increase the space on /tmp

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I'm getting following error;

vp-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device

`df -h
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/root       3.6G  3.5G     0 100% /
 devtmpfs        459M     0  459M   0% /dev
 tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /dev/shm
 tmpfs           463M  6.3M  457M   2% /run
 tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
 tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
 /dev/mmcblk0p1   60M   20M   41M  34% /boot
 tmpfs            93M     0   93M   0% /run/user/1000`

What would be the best way to increase the size of /tmp?

When i try to umount it, I'm getting following error;
umount: /tmp: not mounted

Answer (score 0):

You root partition is full (Mounted on /). Since /tmp is a directory on / you have (at least) two options:

a) Increase size of /. You may do this for example with the GParted live disk: http://gparted.org/livecd.php

b) Mount another partition on /tmp. For this you need to add an entry to your /etc/fstab file like this:

```
/dev/sdb1 /tmp               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       0
```

Replace /dev/sdb1 with a partition you prepared before. You can use the GParted live disk again for preparing the partition.

I suggest you doing a) because otherwise your root partition is full and the system may stop working. b) helps if you have much stuff stored in /tmp.

Hope this helps.